# I am appending data into div using jquery call , it is appending data but in row vice and i want to append side by side

Tags: php, jquery

It is my ajax call that is  returning me the data.

By using ajax call I'm fetching data and appending it but by append it add a new row where as I want to append that data side by side.

```
$.get(base_url+'/get_membership_plan',function(data)
   {
     var units_range = 0; var i=1;
     var membershipLength = data.length ;
     var plan_type='halfyearly'; var discount_factor=0; var months = 1;
 $.each(data,function(index,subcatObj)
 {               

  $('#plans').append('
 <div class="item">
      <div class="item-container"> 
       <h2>1st Year <br> Discount <br> 10%</h2>
      <div class="units-price"> 
       <span class="t-units">1-30 UNITs</span>
       <span class="t-price">$30.00</span>
  </div> 
<div class="net-price"><span class="net-price-e">Net Price</span>
  <span class="red-price">$27.00</span>
</div>
</div>   
<div class="select-btn"><a href="#">Select Plan</a>
</div>
</div>
');
});
});
```

Comment: probable make a html with proper css will help you.

Comment: I have a proper css, when i show data dynamically it is showing properly by using php  but i need to update data when someone select a diff category so when i try it with jquery append it's not showing it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to reinitialize my carousel when I am updating my div section by this way

```
 $('#plans').trigger('add.owl.carousel', ['<div>....']).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```